# PHP not recognizing session passed via PHPSESSID URL param

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm trying to run some benchmark tests on my Zend Framework 1 based web application.

So I've enabled `session.use_trans_id=1` and disabled `session.use_only_cookies=0` 
so that I can pass in a valid PHPSESSID as a query string parameter.

However, it seems that PHP is not recognizing this PHPSESSID and therefore creates a new one.  Any ideas as to how this can happen?

Comment: please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244087/how-can-i-send-phpsessid-in-the-url

Comment: make sure you're using whatever name is assigned in `session.name`. using `foo=...` is pointless is PHP's expecting `bar` as the session parameter.

Comment: Is php also setting a sessionid cookie? I'm curious if for some reason the 'session.use_trans_id=1' is being ignored.

Comment: @BasKuis yes, php is also setting a sessionid cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Apparently, Zend_Session overwrites some of the default ini session settings, unless you explicitly set the option with Zend_Session::setOptions().  Very annoying to the say the least.