# Can someone explain how to use CookieManager in my app?

Tags: php, android, session-cookies, android-volley, android-cookiemanager

I am trying to get User data from a database, and display it on an account page in my app. In my php, I am storing the logged in user in a session. I found out that to access the user session I have to add the sessionId to my string request like:

```
    private void getUserData() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sessionId = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.SID, "SessionID");

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php?PHPSESSID=" + sessionId,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

with sessionId being added to the request. However I am getting an unexpected response code 500 error and I believe it has to do with managing cookies. I am trying to do something like

```
     CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

but not sure how to do this or where to put the cookie manager in the method. 
Thank you.

Comment: Here is the [API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can pass `SessionID` to your server :

1. Send `SessionID` in URL like you mentioned.

   ```
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php?PHPSESSID=" + sessionId,  ...
   ```

   In this case you wont require any `Cookie` to be added in request . So dont need to set `CookieManager`. On php side make sure you have configuration to accept `PHPSESSID` in URL , look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244087/how-can-i-send-phpsessid-in-the-url) for refrence.
2. Put `SessionID` inside `Cookie` header field of your http request. In this case you need to set `CookieManager` to manage cookies which will do the work for you. Here you dont need to send sessionId as URL params.

You seem to be mixing up both these ways.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. How do I accept the `PHPSESSID` on the PHP side? I looked at the link you provided and it said to make sure `session.use_trans_sid` is enabled in the php.ini file. However I am unable to edit this file on the server I am using.